# Работа с ListBox в ASP.NET

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Я разрабатываю чат, у меня есть список комнат. Я его хочу отображать посредством ListBox'a. Для этого я использую LINQtoSQL для выборки данных из базы данных:

```
var db = new LinqChatDataContext();
            listRooms.DataSource = from r in db.Rooms
                                   where r.IsPrivate == "n"
                                   select r.RoomID;
            listRooms.DataBind();
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу отобразить в списке только названия комнат чата, при этом мне необходимо и получить id комнаты, для того, чтобы я передал его в качестве параметра для открытия самого чата. Как это правильно сделать в LINQ запросе и как мне скрыть id комнаты, а отобразить только его название в списке? Возможно мне стоит использовать другой control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеет смысл создать структуру с переопределением метода ToString()

```
    struct Room
    {
       public int Id;
       public string Name;

       public override string ToString()
       {
          return Name;
       }
    }
```

Тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
listRooms.DataSource = from r in db.Rooms 
                       where r.IsPrivate == "n" 
                       select new Room() {Id = r.RoomID, Name = r.RoomName};
```

Из-за того, что метод ToString() переопределен, в списке будут показываться только названия.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!